# avalonia: Как установить иконки в menuItem у элементов верхнего уровня?

Tags: c#, avalonia

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="1"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="2"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

У меня есть такой код, мне нужно установить icons у этих menuItem. Я пробую код с оф сайта

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="1">
         <MenuItem.Icon>
             <Image Source="resm:ItCoursesDesktop.Assets.category.png" />
         </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="2"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

На menuItems 2 уровня и ниже, картинки отображаются. Подскажите в чём проблема, как это сделать?

Comment: Темплейт наверное надо свой определить.